# View the attributes array

Tags: php, arrays

My code is very very simple, I just have this:

```
$element = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($element);
```

which prints out:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [name] => addy'+r+'
            [id] => addy'+r+'
            [cols] => 45
            [rows] => 2
            [disabled] => disabled
        )

    [0] => '+url[r]+'
)
```

Is there anyway I can put the attributes array in a for() loop so that I can add the key/value pairs however and wherever I want on my page?

Comment: Don't rely on `var_dump` / `print_r` for `SimpleXMLElement` objects. They're wily beasts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method

```
$attributes = $element->attributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attr => $val) {
    // tada
}
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch!  Tada! XD

Comment: That certainly is a "Tada"! It works perfectly, thanks! (Gotta wait a few mins before i can accept the answer)